# Issues while implementing a vote skip command for my JDA Music Bot

Tags: java, event-handling, discord, audio-player, discord-jda

This is my first time asking a question here, so please excuse any mistakes I do while posting this. Also I'm somewhat new to programming, so please excuse any bad practices I do as well.

So what I'm trying to do is to create a vote skip command to skip the current song for my JDA Discord music bot. My issue is that I can't find a way to count the votes (in this case reactions added on a message sent by my bot).

The following code snippet shows what I attempted:

```
channel.sendMessage( builder.build() ).queue( (message) -> {
            message.addReaction(Emojis.upvote).queue();
            message.addReaction(Emojis.downvote).queue();

            this.waiter.waitForEvent(
                    
                    // The class the EventWaiter should listen for
                    GuildMessageReactionAddEvent.class,
                    
                    // Conditions
                    
                    // TODO Change event as GuildMessageReactionAddEvent doesn't provide a count for reactions
                    (evt) -> ((GuildMessageReactionAddEvent) evt).getReaction().getCount() >= 10
                    
                            && ((GuildMessageReactionAddEvent) evt).getReaction().getReactionEmote().getEmoji().equals(Emojis.upvote)
                            && evt.getMessageIdLong() == context.getMessage().getIdLong(),
                    
                    // Action if the conditions are fulfilled
                    (evt) -> skip(context),
                    
                    // Timeout after 1 minute
                    1L, TimeUnit.MINUTES,
                    
                    // Action after timeout
                    () -> channel.sendMessage("Not enough votes! Track will be continued").queue());
        } );
```

I realized that *GuildMessageReactionAddEvent* doesn't provide a count for reactions on the message, because it only checks for a single reaction added to the message, meaning that my attempt makes no sense at all.

My idea for a solution to this problem is to use an int variable as a counter that increments each time the *GuildMessageReactionAddEvent* event is fired. Now, as soon as the counter reaches the required amount of votes, the song is skipped, if not, there will be a timeout resulting in the bot sending the "Not enough votes!" message.

I would really appreciate if some of you could write some suggestions or just hints, as to how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do something like this (this is a sketch, not compileable code)

You need to record the number of votes, so your predicate needs to have a side effect.

You can do this with an `AtomicInteger` in the scope of the predicate lambda.

The return value of the predicate depends on the number of votes.

```
       channel.sendMessage( builder.build() ).queue( (message) -> {
            final AtomicInteger voteCounter = new AtomicInteger();
            message.addReaction(Emojis.upvote).queue();
            message.addReaction(Emojis.downvote).queue();

            this.waiter.waitForEvent(

                    // The class the EventWaiter should listen for
                    GuildMessageReactionAddEvent.class,

                    // Conditions

                    (evt) -> {
                        if (((GuildMessageReactionAddEvent) evt).getReaction().getReactionEmote().getEmoji().equals(Emojis.upvote)
                            && evt.getMessageIdLong() == context.getMessage().getIdLong()) {
                            voteCounter.incrementAndGet();
                        }
                        return voteCounter.get() > 10;
                    },

                    // Action if the conditions are fullfilled
                    (evt) -> skip(context),

                    // Timeout after 1 minute
                    1L, TimeUnit.MINUTES,

                    // Action after timeout
                    () -> channel.sendMessage("Not enough votes! Track will be continued").queue());
        } );
    }
```